# Select a div from row and insert value in reactive form

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6

I want to select a segment from row of three and insert value in reactive form. [Here is segment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iduHS.png)

and code is:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <div class="pricingTable">
                    <div class="pricing-content">
                      <div class="set_img"><img class="capa" src="/assets/images/Capa 1.png"></div>

                        <p class="title_segment">STANDARD</p>
                        <div class="Shape-4"></div>
                        <p class="segment_italic">Non refundable <br>AMC ₹ 250/yr</p>
                        <div class="bottom">
                          <div class="txt_400">
                              <i class="fa fa-rupee"> 400</i><span class="gst"> + GST</span>
                        <!-- <a href="#" class="pricingTable-signup">Subscribe Now</a> -->
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <div class="pricingTable">
                    <div class="pricing-content">
                      <div class="set_img"><img class="capa" src="/assets/images/Capa 1.png"></div>

                        <p class="title_segment">PRO</p>
                        <div class="Shape-4"></div>
                        <p class="segment_italic">Non refundable <br>NO AMC</p>
                        <div class="bottom">
                          <div class="txt_400">
                              <i class="fa fa-rupee"> 1000</i><span class="gst"> + GST</span>
                        <!-- <a href="#" class="pricingTable-signup">Subscribe Now</a> -->
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <div class="pricingTable pricingTablepremium">
                    <div class="upper_image">
                        <img class="" src="/assets/images/best_sub.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pricing-content">
                      <div class="set_img img-margin"><img class="capa" src="/assets/images/Capa 1.png"></div>

                        <p class="title_segment">ULTIMATE</p>
                        <div class="Shape-4"></div>
                        <p class="segment_italic">Refundable <br>NO AMC</p>
                        <div class="bottom_pre">
                          <div class="txt_400">
                              <i class="fa fa-rupee"> 2000</i><span class="gst"> + GST</span>
                        <!-- <a href="#" class="pricingTable-signup">Subscribe Now</a> -->
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn_form">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

How to make these segment select able and insert value in reactive form. and the segment should be select able when it click anywhere in that feild.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "select"?

Comment: Have a look at image there are three segments which are static for now but need to be clickable and get that value.

Comment: Please don't hide such information in images, rather explain that in text form. Additionally, all elements are clickable by default - if there should be any logic triggered, explain that further

Comment: I am not hiding anything behind image and i think that was best way to explain scenario. And yet there is no logic triggered behind. I just need to make the segments clickable and value should insert in form.

Comment: So, if clicking such a "segment" should lead to some action, there is logic triggered. And what is wrong with registering a jQuery handler onto that `<div>` and change some hidden form input through that handler?

Comment: On clicking segment it should be act as button and submit in reactive form in angular 6.

Comment: Any suggestions??

Comment: Yes: try to write a simple jQuery handler for that. If that does not work out, share what you've tried and what does not work as expected